# How to show top values from hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

Let's say I have the following info stored in hash:

```
kiwi  15
oranges 25
cherries 30
apples 2
pears 1
```

I want to write code that would display in the descending (by amount) top 3 entries.
So the output should be

```
cherries 30
oranges 25
kiwi 15
```

I can't seem to find the clear answer on that.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? I don't remember ever seeing a question that the author says is for homework, but Stack Overflow is fine with homework questions so I don't understand the reticence. Take a look at [this post on the topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811) from which I take away *"Providing an answer that doesn't help a student learn is not in the student's own best interest"*. So, no, we won't do everything for you; but assistance is fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do as you ask. It uses `sort` with a comparison block that compares each key's corresponding hash value in reverse order. Then each of the first three sorted keys is printed along with its value from the hash.

Note that, if there are multiple hash elements with the same highest value, then this code will print an arbitrary three elements out of those that share the same value

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = qw/
  kiwi     15
  oranges  25
  cherries 30
  apples    2
  pears     1
/;

my @sorted_keys = sort { $data{$b} <=> $data{$a}  } keys %data;

for my $key ( @sorted_keys[0..2] ) {
  print "$key $data{$key}\n";
}
```

**output**

```
cherries 30
oranges 25
kiwi 15
```

---

**Update**

For a more general solution, the (non-core) [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::UtilsBy) module offers a number of utility functions that offer sorts, maxima and minima as a function of the object list. It lets me write the above as

```
use List::UtilsBy qw/ nsort_by /;

my @sorted_keys = nsort_by { $data{$_} } keys %data;

for my $key ( (reverse @sorted_keys)[0..2] ) {
  print "$key $data{$key}\n";
}
```

or, if you prefer the *reverse* in a different place

```
use List::UtilsBy qw/ rev_nsort_by /;

my @sorted_keys = rev_nsort_by { $data{$_} } keys %data;

for my $key ( @sorted_keys[0..2] ) {
  print "$key $data{$key}\n";
}
```

Observe that the difference between the module's `sort_by` and `nsort_by` is equivalent to the difference between the `cmp` and `<=>` comparison operators, respectively.

Both of these alternatives generate identical output to the original above